# How to change editor [disabled] property from directive?

Tags: angular, tinymce, angular-directive

I have [Angular 8.1](https://github.com/angular/angular) app with `PermissionDirective` where i disable elements depending on the table of rights. Directive works except  [TINYMCE editor](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular).

I feel like I'm close with this:

`EditorComponent`

```
<editor permissions
        [init]="tinymce_options.init"
</editor>
```

`PermissionDirective`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[permissions]'
})
export class PermissionsDirective implements OnInit {
 @HostBinding('disabled') disableEditor: boolean;

 public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.disableEditor = true;
 }
}
```

But it reports a error:

> Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'editor'.

But this code with `[disabled]="true"` is working:

```
<editor permissions
        [init]="tinymce_options.init"
        [disabled]="true"
</editor>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cli7uz)

Comment: your permissions directive works only for editor component ?

Comment: Nope, its working for ``fieldset`` ``input`` or ``button``, but for tinymce editor not working.

Comment: As I know so far `@HostBinding` is not working on custom events/properties (it works only for native js events)

Comment: Ah I didn't know, thanks. Maybe I'll try another editor. [This](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html) support ``@Output()`` properties.

Comment: can you put the overall code of the permissions directive ?

Comment: Here is [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cli7uz)

Comment: ok thanks but how your ACL works ? can you add une exemple for how to use permissions with ACL ?